# Image not showing from local storage on React with Multer and Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer, react-fullstack

I've tried multer before in the past and it worked perfectly, but this time I can't get the image to load even when my path is correct and the file exists.

**Here's my app.js on Node**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/tmp/my-uploads',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/tmp/my-uploads')))

const routes = require('./routes');
app.use(routes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port : ', PORT);
})
```

**Multer Middleware**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./tmp/my-uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

**From my react front end to show the image**

```
const image = CarsImages.filter((image) => {
    if(image.primary === true){
      return `http://localhost:3000/tmp/my-uploads/${image.filename}`;
    }
  })
```

**Proof that the image exist, but doesnt load**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIeNZ.png)

**My local storage location**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FRMd.png)

Feel free to ask me further questions if you need more details

Comment: Did you check the Network tab of your browser dev tools ?

Comment: @Clem what do I need to check there? btw I can fetch the API just fine if that's what you're asking. edit: I also tried it on 2 other browsers other than chrome but no luck

Comment: Start by looking which http error you get there. If it s a 404, check the url.

Comment: it says 304 not modified. I used the exact same method I did with multer in the past so I have no clue what I did wrong this time

Comment: In the response preview, do you see the image ? If yes, the issue comme from the frentend app.

Comment: no I can't see it, but I'm still not sure what's wrong in the frontend app